# Can I move a constant out of a continuous function? When?

Tags: continuity

Can I move a constant out of a continuous function? When?

If I have $f(\frac{1}{k}g(x))$

Then is this (ever) same as

If I have $\frac{1}{k}f(g(x))$?

Comment: Is $\sin 2x = 2\sin x$? Here, $f(x) = \sin x, g(x) = x, k=\frac 12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^2$.

The property of $f$ that decides whether you can do that or not, is [homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function). For example, linear functions, such as $f(x) = 21 x$ are homogeneous  (of degree one), but $f(x) = x^2$ is not.

Comment: Good answer that refreshes homogeneity.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x.$

Then

$$f(\frac{1}{k}g(x))=\frac{1}{k^2}x,$$

but

$$\frac{1}{k}f(g(x))=\frac{1}{k}x.$$

Comment: But are there exceptions, when the property would hold?